# Has Opera 10 beta dropped support for the background-size CSS rule?

Tags: linux, opera, css

Opera 9.5, according to [this Opera Dev article](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css-text-shadows-and-background-sizing/), and also [this MDC article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-background-size) has support for the CSS 3 [background-size](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size) rule through -o-background-size vendor extension.  I've been playing around today with the code from the MDC article and have got it to work in Firefox and Chromium, but it doesn't work in Opera 10 Beta 2:

```
body {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url('bg-image-1.jpg');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;           /* Gecko 1.9.2 (Firefox 3.6) */
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%;             /* Opera 9.5 */
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;        /* Safari 3.0 */
    -khtml-background-size: 100% 100%;         /* Konqueror 3.5.4 */
    -moz-border-image: url('bg-image-1.jpg') 0;/* Gecko 1.9.1 (Firefox 3.5) */
}
```

In fact, Opera's own example doesn't seem to work in Opera 10 Beta 2, which leads me to believe support has somehow been removed, but there's no mention of it in the [beta 1](http://www.opera.com/docs/changelogs/linux/1000b1/) or [beta 2](http://www.opera.com/docs/changelogs/linux/1000b2/) changelogs.

Can someone who still has Opera 9.5 installed check the [the Opera example works](http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/314/background-sizing02.html) (should see green bars at the sides of the page)?  And if anyone's seen any documentation for changes in background-size support between 9.5 and 10 beta please post a link.

Here's what it looks like in the Linux build of 10b2:

[image: Screenshot in Opera 10b2 on Ubuntu]

Comment: The linux beta is probably a different build number where the property was temporarily removed or just buggy.

Comment: Didn't work in the beta1 either - I checked before upgrading it.

Comment: Linux 10.0 released, -o-background-size still broken :(

Comment: Just had another look at this thread - any improvement with Opera 11?

Comment: @Ant `background-size` is working for me in Opera 11.10, although the Opera example I linked to doesn't work because that only lists `-o-background-size`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is no longer valid

Answer (score 1):

For everyone's future reference, `background-size` is supported in the [Linux build of the Opera 10.50 pre-alpha](http://snapshot.opera.com/unix/labs-6177/).  Although `-o-background-size` is no longer supported, so their example still doesn't work, by my ones do ;)

Answer (score 0):

Opera 9.64:

[image: AW3S0ME ALT T3XT DESCR1PTION]

Comment: Thanks.  For me the image repeats across the page so there's a green bar in the middle.  I've logged a defect with Opera, see what happens.